# Swing Panel in Panel different Layouts

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm quite new to Swing and Java.

What I tried to accomplish is panel containing and textfield and below some tags (JLabel).

Unfortunately I am not allowed to post images yet. So here's a scribble of the layout I want to create and what I get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsfwijlp77xssmk/panel-in-panel.png?dl=0

```
add(textFieldTags);
tagWrapperPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
tagWrapperPanel.setVisible(true);
add(tagWrapperPanel);
JLabel label = new JLabel("dsgsdgs");
setForeground(Color.WHITE);
setBackground(new Color(96, 153, 58));
setVisible(true);
tagWrapperPanel.add(label);
```

The result is a tiny textfield and a label beside of it. I also tried different layout combinations but without any luck.

Can you suggest me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `JTextField myTextField = new JTextField(10);` where the parameter (here 10) is the number of visible columns that you want the JTextField to have. For better more complete help, post a small but compilable and runnable program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();

JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
contentPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 1"));
contentPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 2"));
contentPanel.add(new JLabel("Label 3"));

window.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
window.add(contentPanel,     BorderLayout.CENTER);

window.setSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setVisible(true);
```